# query on xpath, xml

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have **input XML** file. As below.

```
<maindocument>
<first>
    <testing>random text</testing>
    <checking>random test</checking>
</first>
<testing>
<testing>sample</testing>
<checking>welcome</checking>
</testing>
<import>
    <downloading>valuable text</downloading>
</import>
</maindocument>
```

Here is the **output XML** i want

```
<maindocument>
<import>
    <doctype>Valuable</doctype>
    <docint>text</docint>
</import>
</maindocument>
```

When i searched in Google, i am getting the result as `XSL:Copy`.

Comment: What is the targetable logic of the transformation?

Comment: Your overall need isn't very clear.  Looks like you want to discard everything in `<maindocument>` except for the contents of `<import>` and transform that some how.  But what are the criteria for transforming the contents of `<downloading>` into `<doctype>` and `<docint>`

Comment: With the help of XSlT using absolute or relative path i need to take the data only from <import> element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="import">
     <maindocument>
      <xsl:copy>
       <doctype><xsl:value-of select="substring-before(*, ' ')"/></doctype>
       <docint><xsl:value-of select="substring-after(*, ' ')"/></docint>
      </xsl:copy>
     </maindocument>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<maindocument>
    <first>
        <testing>random text</testing>
        <checking>random test</checking>
    </first>
    <testing>
        <testing>sample</testing>
        <checking>welcome</checking>
    </testing>
    <import>
        <downloading>valuable text</downloading>
    </import>
</maindocument>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<maindocument>
   <import>
      <doctype>valuable</doctype>
      <docint>text</docint>
   </import>
</maindocument>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try ...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
 <xsl:copy> 
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
 </xsl:copy> 
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="first|testing|checking" />

<xsl:template match="import">
 <xsl:copy> 
  <doctype><xsl:value-of select="substring-before(.,' ')" /></doctype>
  <docint><xsl:value-of select="substring-after(.,' ')" /></docint>  
 </xsl:copy> 
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```